# UIView overlay is unresponsive to touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I display a UIView overlay in our app by including the view as one of two siblings in a parent view and having the frame.y coordinate just offscreen to the bottom. I then animate the moving of this frame up over the sibling. The hiddenYOrigin value is a float to hold the original offscreen y value:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    hiddenYOrigin = self.frame.origin.y;
}
```

Then I call showAnimated from the other view:

```
- (void)showAnimated
{
    CGRect frame = self.superview.frame;
    frame.origin.y = -hiddenYOrigin + 20;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.superview.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self.controller overlayDidShow:self];
    }];
}
```

This does properly show the overlay and is the exact same mechanism we use in our other apps, but for whatever reason in this app the overlay is completely unresponsive to touch. It has several buttons for various actions including hiding the overlay and yet nothing touch is received.

I added a hitTest function to debug whether any touches were coming through but no touches ever fire the hitTest.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is the output from running the "po" command mentioned by @robmayoff:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0xbb47ab0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb47f70>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0xbb47b90>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0xbae7780; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbab2370>; layer = <CALayer: 0xba5be40>>
   |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0xbafb770; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xbaf6090>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0xbb783d0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb78480>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10b6efc0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6f020>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10b6d920; frame = (54 20; 266 460); autoresize = LM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6d980>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0xc215e00; frame = (0 44; 266 400); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b6ced0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6ca70>; contentOffset: {0, -20}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x10b6d1d0; frame = (0 0; 266 400); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6d240>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CustomButtonCell: 0x10ba6d40; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 202; 266 44); text = 'Toggle All'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba6c00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x10ba6ed0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10ba7160>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba70a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b67390; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b67480>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10ba7350; frame = (0 0; 266 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10ba7560>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba73c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10ba75b0; frame = (15 0; 236 44); text = 'Toggle All'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba7660>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x10ba6030; frame = (0 164; 266 38); text = 'Categories'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba5fa0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x10ba61c0; frame = (0 0; 266 38); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10ba6450>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba6390>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10ba6640; frame = (0 0; 266 38); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10ba6850>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba66b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10ba68a0; frame = (15 0; 236 38); text = 'Categories'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba6950>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SegmentedControlCell: 0x10b9afd0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 120; 266 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9b200>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x10b9b430; frame = (0 0; 266 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b9b6c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9b600>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10b9b8b0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b9bac0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9b920>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISegmentedControl: 0x10b9bd30; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9be70>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISegment: 0x10ba4ef0; frame = (178 0; 88 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba4e40>> - Room
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10ba5630; frame = (88 0; 2 44); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = -1030; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba56b0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISegmentLabel: 0x10bcede0; frame = (13.5 11; 43 20); text = 'Room'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bcee90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISegment: 0x10ba43f0; frame = (89 0; 87 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba43b0>> - Category
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10ba4c50; frame = (87 0; 2 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = -1030; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba4cd0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISegmentLabel: 0x10bcfe40; frame = (10.5 11; 66 20); text = 'Category'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd0400>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISegment: 0x10ba0fb0; frame = (0 0; 87 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba1130>> - Time
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10ba3ec0; frame = (87 0; 2 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = -1030; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba3cf0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISegmentLabel: 0x10bce190; frame = (35 11; 35 20); text = 'Time'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bce240>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x10b9a210; frame = (0 82; 266 38); text = 'Order By'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b99870>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x10b9a3a0; frame = (0 0; 266 38); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b9a5f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9a570>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10b9a7e0; frame = (0 0; 266 38); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b9a9f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9a850>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10b9aa40; frame = (15 0; 236 38); text = 'Order By'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9aaf0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CustomButtonCell: 0x10b95850; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 38; 266 44); text = 'All Days'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b95a80>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x10b95cb0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b95f40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b95e80>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b63a10; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b63ac0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10b96130; frame = (0 0; 266 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b96340>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b961a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10b96390; frame = (15 0; 236 44); text = 'All Days'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b96440>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b638b0; frame = (224 15; 18 14); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b63850>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x10b948b0; frame = (0 0; 266 38); text = 'Dates'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b94770>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x10b94a40; frame = (0 0; 266 38); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b94cd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b94c10>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10b94ec0; frame = (0 0; 266 38); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b950d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b94f30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10b95120; frame = (15 0; 236 38); text = 'Dates'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b951d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x10b93ea0; frame = (0 0; 266 0); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b94030>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x10b94060; frame = (0 0; 266 0); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b942d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b94230>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10b944c0; frame = (0 0; 266 0); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b946d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b94530>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x10b93320; frame = (0 0; 266 0); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b934b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x10b934e0; frame = (0 0; 266 0); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b93770>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b936b0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10b93960; frame = (0 0; 266 0); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b93b70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b939d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CategorySelectionCell: 0xbb9e3b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 246; 266 44); text = 'Communication'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9f790>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbb9f9c0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb9fc30>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9fb90>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b3b070; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b95b00>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b32560; frame = (0 -0.5; 266 45); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbadc9a0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbb9fe20; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbba0030>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9fe90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbba0080; frame = (65 0; 186 44); text = 'Communication'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba0130>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bbabf0; frame = (25 7; 30 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bbac90>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CategorySelectionCell: 0xbba2360; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 290; 266 44); text = 'Entertainment'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba22f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbba24f0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbba2720>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba2320>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xbadc850; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba2ce0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b7e4a0; frame = (0 -0.5; 266 45); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b82c30>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbba2910; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbba2b20>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba2980>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbba2b70; frame = (65 0; 186 44); text = 'Entertainment'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba2c20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bbb040; frame = (25 7; 30 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bbb0e0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CategorySelectionCell: 0xbba6110; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 334; 266 44); text = 'Event Technology'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba6090>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbba62a0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbba64b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba2ee0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b9d5f0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9d6c0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b9d750; frame = (0 -0.5; 266 45); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9d840>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbba66a0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbba68b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba6710>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbba6900; frame = (65 0; 186 44); text = 'Event Technology'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba69b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bbb450; frame = (25 7; 30 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bbb4f0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CategorySelectionCell: 0xbba9ea0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 378; 266 44); text = 'Exhibitor Mgmt.'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba9e20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbbaa030; frame = (0 0; 266 44); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbbaa240>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbba6c70>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bb9110; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bb9220>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bb92c0; frame = (0 -0.5; 266 45); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bb93b0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbbaa430; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbbaa640>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbbaa4a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbbaa690; frame = (65 0; 186 44); text = 'Exhibitor Mgmt.'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbbaa740>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bbb860; frame = (25 7; 30 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bbb900>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10bbab90; frame = (0 365; 266 15); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bb7b30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b6cca0; frame = (0 376.5; 266 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6cae0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bc4850; frame = (262.5 -20; 3.5 400); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bc4920>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b6d9b0; frame = (266 0; 3 460); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6da30>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b8eba0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b8dd90>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10baaa50; frame = (0 0; 266 44); text = ' '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b94860>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x10ba47c0; frame = (70 6; 140 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b9ded0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bc9850; frame = (0 0; 140 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bc86d0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x10b725e0; frame = (50 11; 40 22); text = 'Filter'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ba45e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0xc215a00; frame = (0 44; 266 400); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b6c680>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6c220>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10b88340; frame = (0 -400; 266 400); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b88040>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x10b6c980; frame = (0 0; 266 400); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6c9f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableViewCell: 0xbb9d2d0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 364; 266 76); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9d210>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbb9d470; frame = (0 0; 266 76); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb9d700>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9d640>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbb9b900; frame = (0 0; 266 76); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb9bac0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9d8f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MTLabel: 0xbb9bb70; frame = (20 10; 250 40); text = 'Effortless CEU Session Ma...'; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9bc10>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb9c050; frame = (20 56; 58.5181 12); text = 'Bayside C • '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9c100>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb9c530; frame = (78.5181 56; 129.216 12); text = 'Mar. 7 1:00pm - 2:00pm'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9c630>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xbb9f1b0; frame = (0 74; 266 2); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9f2a0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableViewCell: 0xbb9a0b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 284; 266 60); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb99ff0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbb9a250; frame = (0 0; 266 60); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb9a4e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9a420>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbb9a6d0; frame = (0 0; 266 60); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb9a8e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9a740>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MTLabel: 0xbb9a990; frame = (20 12; 250 20); text = 'Lunch - Day 1'; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9aa30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb9ae70; frame = (20 38; 104.457 12); text = 'Main Dining Room • '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9af20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb9b450; frame = (124.457 38; 135.888 12); text = 'Mar. 7 12:00pm - 1:00pm'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9b560>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xbb9d0b0; frame = (0 58; 266 2); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb9d1a0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableViewCell: 0xbb99350; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 204; 266 60); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb99290>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbb994f0; frame = (0 0; 266 60); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb99780>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb996c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbb97990; frame = (0 0; 266 60); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb97b40>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb99970>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MTLabel: 0xbb97bf0; frame = (20 12; 250 20); text = 'Keynote Address'; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb97c90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb980d0; frame = (20 38; 90.7769 12); text = 'Grand Ballroom • '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb98180>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb985b0; frame = (110.777 38; 135.216 12); text = 'Mar. 7 9:00am - 12:00pm'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb986b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xbb99e90; frame = (0 58; 266 2); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb99f80>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableViewCell: 0xbb95890; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 124; 266 60); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb95830>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbb95a30; frame = (0 0; 266 60); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb95cc0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb95c00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbb95eb0; frame = (0 0; 266 60); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb96140>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb95fa0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MTLabel: 0xbb961f0; frame = (20 12; 250 20); text = 'Welcome / Meet and Greet'; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb96310>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb96750; frame = (20 38; 69.0776 12); text = 'Front Foyer • '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb96800>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb975e0; frame = (89.0776 38; 127.872 12); text = 'Mar. 7 8:00am - 9:00am'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb976c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xbb99130; frame = (0 58; 266 2); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb99220>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableViewCell: 0xbb94a10; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 64; 266 60); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb92f40>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xbb94d30; frame = (0 0; 266 60); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb912d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb92ff0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xbb939a0; frame = (0 0; 266 60); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xbb93bf0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb93a50>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MTLabel: 0xbb93fc0; frame = (20 12; 250 20); text = 'Registration Desk - Day 1'; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb94100>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb946c0; frame = (20 38; 69.0776 12); text = 'Front Foyer • '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb94770>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbb94fd0; frame = (89.0776 38; 134.544 12); text = 'Mar. 7 8:00am - 10:00am'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb95080>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xbb97250; frame = (0 58; 266 2); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbb972d0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISearchBar: 0x10b6feb0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); text = ''; autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10b704a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b70040>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10b70270; frame = (0 0.5; 266 43.5); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b702d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISearchBarBackground: 0x10b707a0; frame = (0 0; 266 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b708f0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISearchBarTextField: 0x10b736a0; frame = (8 5; 250 33); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10bc36c0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b72d60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldBorderView: 0x10b7bc60; frame = (0 0; 250 33); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b7bd70>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b76390; frame = (92.5 9.5; 12.5 12.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b76410>> - Search
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UISearchBarTextFieldLabel: 0x10b7c580; frame = (112.5 0; 137.5 33); text = 'Search'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b7c6d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xbb920f0; frame = (0 -1; 266 1); layer = <CALayer: 0xbb92150>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b6c450; frame = (0 396.5; 266 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b6c290>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableHeaderView: 0x10bd1d30; frame = (0 44; 266 20); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd1db0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bd1ec0; frame = (0 0; 266 20); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd1e50>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10bd2020; frame = (10 0; 246 20); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd1f70>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10bd2650; frame = (10 0; 236 20); text = 'Mar. 7 8:00am'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd2290>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableHeaderView: 0x10bd1830; frame = (0 184; 266 20); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd18b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bd23a0; frame = (0 0; 266 20); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd2420>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10bd2530; frame = (10 0; 246 20); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd25e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10bcead0; frame = (10 0; 236 20); text = 'Mar. 7 9:00am'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd2db0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableHeaderView: 0x10bd3720; frame = (0 264; 266 20); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd37a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bd3890; frame = (0 0; 266 20); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd3820>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10bd39f0; frame = (10 0; 246 20); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd3930>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10bd48c0; frame = (10 0; 236 20); text = 'Mar. 7 12:00pm'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd4970>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <SessionTableHeaderView: 0xbb67e40; frame = (0 344; 266 20); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xbbae740>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xbb97180; frame = (0 0; 266 20); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbbae220>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xbba2d90; frame = (10 0; 246 20); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xbbae250>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10bd1510; frame = (10 0; 236 20); text = 'Mar. 7 1:00pm'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bd15c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10bc4f50; frame = (262.5 0; 3.5 400); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bc5020>> - (null)
```

...

Comment: Are you sure that UI interactions are enabled for the view?

Comment: Yes, I set userInteractionEnabled = YES on the view and I even did a loop through all the views in the hierarchy just to make sure they were all set to userInteractionEnabled and all show as enabled.

Comment: In the debugger console, run `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.  Copy the output and paste it into your question.

Comment: I added the output but had to truncate to fit within the SO character limit of 30,000.

Answer (score 0):

I gather the code you posted is part of the implementation of a custom UIView subclass you've created?

Why are you manipulating your superview's frame? That doesn't look right.

For a given view, its bounds are in its local coordinate system, and the view's frame is in the parent view's coordinate system. Manipulating a view's frame.origin moves the view inside its parent view. Manipulating a view's superview.frame would move the superview around in **ITS** superview, which does not look right, and could have unintended side-effects.

Comment: Good question. I inherited this code from a previous employee and it always worked. I suppose I can show the overlay another way, but this worked well to create a slide-up animation from offscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Since I never could determine why one of the sibling views (the parentViewController.rightDrawer in my case) was capturing all the touches instead of the overlay I just punted and came up with this solution:

When showing the overlay I add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view that keeps grabbing the touches:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap  =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

tap.delegate = self;
[self.parentViewController.rightDrawer addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then have my handleTap function translate the CGPoints and fire the appropriate code:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [sender.view convertPoint:[sender locationInView:[sender.view self]] toView:self.scanOverlay];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bottomScanButton.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [self bottomScanButtonPressed:self.bottomScanButton];
        }
        else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.scanOverlay.closeButton.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [self hideScanOverlayAnimated:YES didScan:NO];
        }
        else if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.scanOverlay.modeButton.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [self.scanOverlay modeButtonPressed:self.scanOverlay.modeButton];
        }
    }
}
```

Since I only had three buttons that had any user interaction I just detect if the converted touchpoint is touching any of my controls and fire the correct logic.

Then when hiding my overlay I remove the tap recognizer:

```
// Remove the tap recognizer that was added to catch the taps coming from the right drawer
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.parentViewController.rightDrawer.gestureRecognizers) {

    if([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [self.parentViewController.rightDrawer removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
}
```

I could have created an iVar and only remove the one recognizer, but since I don't have any others I just nuke any UITapGestureRecognizer.

Kludgy, but I have a deadline. That's life unfortunately. Have to catch it on the next refactor.